Is there a difference between GW and GWe?
How would you explain the difference between "GW" and "GWe" when talking about electricity generation?
Is there a way to convert one into the other easily if you don't have any underlying data?


How would you explain the difference between "GW" and "GWe" when talking about electricity generation?

A gigawatt is a gigawatt. "GWe" just is a gigawatt with an additional specifier that means it's a gigawatt of electricity. "GWth" would be a gigawatt with an additional specifier meaning it's a gigawatt of thermal power.
If for example someone claims to build a 1600 GW nuclear power plant, it's most likely a 1600 GWe plant, since electric output is the most important parameter here. Most likely it would then be a 5000 GWth plant, since nuclear power plants operate at bit above 30% efficiency. So thermal power plants have two powers of interest: thermal power and electric power. Cogeneration plants have three powers of interest: total thermal power, delivered heat power, and electric power. The efficiency of cogeneration is usually about 90%, so delivered heat power and electric power together are about 90% of the total thermal power.
Also for heating there are two powers of interest and the most interesting power there is heat power, so for example a 9 kW ground source heat pump means it delivers 9 kW of heat. Most likely it uses less than 3 kW of electricity to do that, since ground source heat pumps generally operate at COP of above 3, often above 4 too.

Is there a way to convert one into the other easily if you don't have any underlying data?

You need to know the application. For heat pumps, COP can be used to convert between heat power and electric power. For electricity generation in thermal power plants, efficiency is the convertor. Generally COP and efficiency can be estimated, since bad products have been displaced from the market, and it's unusual to find a heat pump with poor COP or a thermal power plant with poor efficiency.
For wind power and solar power GW and GWe are the same, since there's no heat involved. They don't operate thermally. However, wind and solar powers suffer from capacity factor being less than 100%, since sunshine and wind are not at maximum always.

On power generation, GWe is the power that can be delivered as electricity. Note: the output, and often the maximal power.
GW: it depends, it can be the same as above, or just the power at input. On thermal power plant (gas, coal, nuclear): it is the power provided by heat. Then you need to convert to electricity, so you lose a lot of power, on the other hand, you may use extra heat for other reasons (district heating, mostly for industry or agriculture).
Note: on thermal power plant both components (heat and generator) are nearly independent, so you can switch independently (and newer generators are much more efficient). But the thermal part is the part which creates most of costs.
How to convert? It is not easy: check plants with similar technology, and calculate the efficiency. GWe being 1/6 to 1/3 of GW may be good estimates of thermal plants.
For other plants: you use often uses only one number.
Note: do not confuse such maximum power with energy delivered per year (often given as "the number of households"). Both are powers, but one is peak, the other is the expected output (sun, wind availability, maintenance of thermal plants, etc.)

GWe definitely won't be 1/6 of thermal GW. A power plant with 16% efficiency is so poor not even Soviet Union would build such a plant.

Right. I added wrongly the extra energy (mining, transport) only on one side. (or better, I should not have added it: we are discussing on GW_th / GWe, so at power plant limit)
